# Tomcat - Having multiple instances of ParallelWebappClassLoader to reload certain classes

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

I am trying to extend the `ParallelWebappClassLoader` so that upon a specific trigger I can reload a specified class using `com.foo.my.ClazzName`. I understand that `ParallelWebappClassLoader` maintains its own cache and returns the class from it's cache if found by `findLoadedClass0()`. To make sure that class can be linked correctly I think I need to reload the class using a new instance of my extended `ParallelWebappClassLoader`. something like the following:

```
public Class<?> loadClassAgain(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    // lock method is internal which I have inherited.

    synchronized(getClassLoadingLock(name)) {
        String binaryPathName = convertNameToPath(name, true);
        this.resourceEntries.remove(binaryPathName);
        MyParallelClassLoader loader = new MyParallelClassLoader (this.getParent());
        loader.start(); // Starts resource context.

        // I have provided loadClass def such that it goes to super.loadClass()
        return loader.loadClass(name,true);
    }
```

Is this the right approach, has anyone tried it previously? I am trying to avoid tomcar context reload i.e. the whole server restarts. Instead, I am aiming to reload a specific class (or classes) by given name.

I am not sure if using `URLClassLoader` is a better approach but I decided to start with tomcat's own to save some trouble - may be this is wrong!?

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: This isn't really a "safe" operation as far as the container is concerned for a number of reasons. Is this something you want to do in order to improve the speed of development by avoiding context restarts?

Comment: Hi. Yes I want to be able to fully reload a class to account for changes in method addition/definition, static variable additon/changes etc. Basically, the ability to load my new definition without fully stopping Catalina lifecycle for my webapp. I have an agent which can redefine classes but it&#39;s restricted to JVM instrumentation specifics. I don&#39;t want to use 3rd pary tools because they aren&#39;t permitted in my development lib whitelist. I hope I have outlined it properly. Let me know if it&#39;s unclear.

Comment: Reloading a single class is not safe because such changes won't be noticed by other classes and then weird things can happen such as `MethodNotFoundError` or, even more insidious, an out-of-date "constant" used by some other class when you change a single target class. Things become more complicated when trying to reload a single class because there may be objects of the "old" type still live in the heap. Your best bet is to discard the old `ClassLoader` and instantiate a new one with the new `Class` available to it. Convincing your application to use the new `ClassLoader` is the hard part.

Comment: Yes that's where I've been struggling. Without using the start() in WebabbClassLoaderBase it's getting difficult to reload all classes.